Getting node-pandoc to return filename with error
I replaced the default markdown processor in Eleventy 2.0.1 with node-pandoc like thus:
const nodePandoc = require('node-pandoc');
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
  async function convertMarkdownToHtml(markdown) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      nodePandoc(markdown, '-d _data/defaults.yaml', (err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.error(`Pandoc error: ${err.message}`);
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
...
}

I am letting the processor continue even with errors because they're often minor warnings about missing citations and such. However, I would very much like the output to pinpoint which file caused what error. Right now only all it does is show the error message, for example:
Pandoc error: YAML pa
Pandoc error: rse exception at line 7, column 0,
while scanning a simple key:
could not find ex
Pandoc error: pected ':'

I am not experienced with JavaScript and could not get the path module to get me the offending markdown file.
